# Making a bootstrap div scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div on the side of my page that I want to add a lot of information to, therefore I want it to be scrollable. I have tried using overflow: scroll; and the scroll bar appears, but does not allow the user to scroll down through the content.

website: explorecanterbury.co.uk

HTML

```
<div class="info-div">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6" style="background-color:orange;">
        <div class="close"><span class="close-btn"></spam></div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <h2 class="subtitle">Canterbury Cathedral</h1>
            <img src="img/test.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <img src="img/test.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p>St Augustine, the first Archbishop of Canterbury, arrived on the coast of Kent as a missionary to England in 597 AD. He came from Rome, sent by Pope Gregory the Great.</p>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Find out more...</h1>
            <p>SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS GO HERE</p>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Related Attractions</h1>
              <p>St Augustine, the first Archbishop of Canterbury, arrived on the coast of Kent as a missionary to England in 597 AD. He came from Rome, sent by Pope Gregory the Great.</p>
              <p>St Augustine, the first Archbishop of Canterbury, arrived on the coast of Kent as a missionary to England in 597 AD. He came from Rome, sent by Pope Gregory the Great.</p>
          </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.info-div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
z-index: 10;
height: 100%
max-height: 1340px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: fundamental;
  src: url(file://C:/Users/Sara/Documents/ExploreCanterbury/fonts/FUNDR___.TTF);
}

.close-btn {
  background-image: url(file://C:/Users/Sara/Documents/ExploreCanterbury/img/close.png);
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  display: block;
}

.close{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.subtitle{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: fundamental;
}
```

Comment: there is no content to scroll. The content fits the height of the box.

Comment: if you go onto inspect element you can see that it wont scroll when the content overflows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon in `.info-div` class, which makes your css invalid and the `height` property not to be set.

```
.info-div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%
  max-height: 1340px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

So add a semi-colon after `height:100%`, and change `position` to be `absolute` and `width:100%;`. Try this

```
.info-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1340px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` in CSS for `info-div` class,

```
  height: 100%
```

should be

```
  height: 100%;
```

And also the content is fit in the height.You can get scrollbar if height set to any certain `px`.
example:

```
 height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a height value so that it looks something like this.

```
height:400px;
height:100%;
max-height:1340px;
```

If you limit the height in the inspector to 400px as it is then the scroll works. Currently there's not enough content to reach that max height you have set so there is no need for the scroll to occur.

However, I think that your cloud animations are slowing the scroll down to make it "juttery". I don't have a solution to that I'm afraid. It may just be my browser (Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can add class="overflow-auto" on the div.

```html
<div class="info-div overflow-auto">
```